# The movieplayer can not display subtitles on the IOS7.0.4

Tags: ios, ios7, mpmovieplayer, subtitle, http-live-streaming

The movieplayer can not display subtitles(en or fr ) with the below .m3u8 file on the ios 7.0.4 , but on another version(ios7.1 , ios8) ,the subtitles can display( default subtitle is English).
Which master could tell me the reason and how to fix it

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",AUTOSELECT= YES,DEFAULT=YES,FORCED=NO,URI="english/multisegment.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",LANGUAGE="fr",NAME="French",AUTOSELECT=Y ES,DEFAULT=NO,FORCED=NO,URI="french/multisegment.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=200000, SUBTITLES="subs"
../clear/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=311111, SUBTITLES="subs"
../clear/prog_index.m3u8
```

Comment: No guys answer to me ?